# GridBagLayout: Setting the position of components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I read some questions which stated that GBL is better than the normal GridLayout for positioning the components.

Links: 
[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906331/how-do-you-set-the-position-of-button-in-grid-layout) , [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028917/how-to-position-components-with-gridbaglayout), [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Well so I tried to add some components (buttons) to my GBL but it somehow always centers my components. The only way to seperate the 2 Buttons is to place Dummies into my project which looks awful.

```
public class GridGUI extends JPanel {

private JButton button;

public GridGUI() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints comps = makeGbc(0,1);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    button = new JButton("Datei speichern");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
    panel.add(button);
    add(panel,comps);

    comps = makeGbc(1,1);
    button = new JButton("Datei laden");
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(new JPanel());
    panel.add(button);
    add(panel,comps);
}

private GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int x, int y) {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridx = x;
    gbc.gridy = y;
    gbc.weightx = x;
    gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    gbc.anchor = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.LINE_START : GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    return gbc;
}

public static void showGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pop-Art-Collage");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new GridGUI());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            showGUI();
        }

    });
}

}
```

[image: The GUI]

But I want them to appear at the top of the GUI and not in the center.

Also I tried to resize the buttons by using `button.setSize(x,y)` but they always stayed the same.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Okay I tried now the solution I got but I got into some other problems.

```
    GridBagConstraints comps = makeGbc(0,1,20,50,0,0);
    button = new JButton("Datei speichern");
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,25));
    add(button,comps);
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Datei laden");
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,25));
    comps = makeGbc(1,1,20,150,0,100);
    add(button2,comps);
```

[image: new]

Here is my problem that I set the prefered size for both buttons the same but it still doesnt show correctly for the second one. 
(the 4 Numbers after x,y of makeGbc are the Insets values top,left,bottom,right)

Answer (score 3):

Your buttons are in the middle, not on the top, because you place it there:

```
gbc.anchor = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.LINE_START : GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
```

`GridBagConstraints.LINE_END` and `GridBagConstraints.LINE_START` puts components in the centere. Try with:

```
gbc.anchor = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START : GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
```

Also:

- try to set size of buttons with `setPreferredSize()`, GBL with `frame.pack()` should respect choosen sizes,
- you add your buttons to new `JPanels`, and then to container with GBL, so it place your buttons in center. Add your buttons directly to `GridGUI`, and it will be placed according to `GridBagConstraints()`, for example:

  ```
  button = new JButton("Datei laden");
  add(button,makeGbc(1,1));
  ```
- you use one class field `JButton button`, for two different buttons, this way you are not able to change first button state, after you change button reference - if you try to change for example text in button, from different part of application, by using `button` class field you can access only second button.

**EDIT**

I am not sure what effect you exactly want, but I would try to add your `GridGUI` first to new `JPanel`, then to `JFrame` (in main method):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pop-Art-Collage");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT)); //add FlowLayout.LEFT,
panel.add(new GridGUI());
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Now, the FlowLayout should keep all components to left, and you can control the space between buttons by changing insets. For first button, a would set all inputs to 0, and in second one, the `new Insets(0,x,0,0)`, where x is desired distance. Like this:

```
add(button,makeGbc(0,1,0,0,0,0));
add(button2,makeGbc(0,1,0,150,0,0));
```

But I am not sure, how this set of layouts will behave when you add more components, so the easier way, is to use only `frame.pack()`, without `frame.setSize()`, and then extend it by adding new components. Then it should be easier to predict how changes will work.

Also pay attention to a fact, that in a example code above, you set different `setPreferredSize()` for both buttons.

Comment: (1+), `The only way to seperate the 2 Buttons is to place Dummies into my project which looks awful.` you are using "insets" which control the space between the two components, so change the insets.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you for your comment, I edited my answer already! I obviously didn't know that.

Comment: but in which way do I have to work with Insets? What are they supposed to do? If I change the Insets to e.g (100,0,0,0) it changes nothing

Comment: @m.cekiera Okay I know how the Insets work now after a bit of googleing. They are pretty straightforward. But I updated my question, maybe you could look into this?

Comment: @m.cekiera the problem with the JPanel now is that my Insets formatting is weird now. The Components aren't at the positions they were before. What I need is that the button "Datei laden" is the same size as the other button. I set the preferred size to the same as the "Datei speichern" button but the Insets are fcking it up so it looks bigger somehow.

Comment: @NhatNienneI updated my answer again. If it will not work properly, I encourage you to post new Question, with all relevant code, because it is hard to say what is wrong without it.